# Split a camelCase string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, camelcasing

I have a Camel case string like this `s = 'ThisIsASampleString'` and I want to split into an array using the capital letters as the delimiting point. I am expecting this:

```
['This', 'Is', 'A', 'Sample', 'String']
```

Here is what I have done so far

```
s = "ThisIsASampleString";
var regex = new RegExp('[A-Z]',"g");
var arr = s.split(re);
```

But this is not giving me the correct result because it removes the matched character. I am getting this array as my result `["his",  "s",  "",  "tring"]`. It has removed all the matched capital letters.

How should I avoid this behavior and keep the matched characters also in my result array?

Comment: This is not camel-casing. A camel-cased string would start with a lower-case letter. This is sometimes called "Pascal-casing".

Comment: Noted @torazaburo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regex would split based on the uppercase but the result array doesn't include the matched value. Instead use [positive look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert the position.

```js
s = "ThisIsASampleString";
var arr = s.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);

console.log(arr);
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/Ueb6Gq/1)

---

Or you can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method instead.

```js
s = "ThisIsASampleString";
var arr = s.match(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/g);

console.log(arr);
```

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/X60F0x/2)

Comment: Although I have a question, why is it happening, why those capital letters were getting removed upon matching?

Comment: @Ezio :  the string is getting split based on the matched separator.... check the MDN docs it may help you : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split