# How to split a string with camelcase and also with uppercase using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my string to original:

```
myCamelCaseSTRINGToSPLIT
```

expected result:

```
my Camel Case STRING To SPLIT
```

Current regex I'm using is

```
(?=[A-Z])
```

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to split camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379254/regex-to-split-camel-case) or a duplicate of [Split a camelCase string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41196276/split-a-camelcase-string-with-regex)

Comment: There is no way to distinguish in "STRINGTo" where the To begins. Technically putting STRING all in caps makes it non CamelCase

Answer (score 2):

Please use this regular expression.

```
yourString.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1").replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g, " $1")
```

> or

```
yourString.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, " $1")
```

[Live Demo with two times Replace](http://jsfiddle.net/PeYYQ/540/)

[Live Demo with single time Replace](http://jsfiddle.net/PeYYQ/546/)

Comment: The second `replace` adds a couple extra spaces between the first few words.

Comment: check my live demos you will see the differences @thgaskell